# How to get first argument of each parameter in a list in shell

Tags: list, shell, for-loop

I have a list in shell.

```
LISTNODES='
name1 labels="{..}"
name2 labels="{...}"
'
```

Now I'm looping through the list (for-loop). But I want only to take the name out of the loop.

So something like this

```
for i in $LISTNODES; do
    i = #command to keep name (and cut labels...)
    echo $i #this output must be name1 and for the next loop name2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
${i%% *}
```

inside your loop.

(Important: There must be exactly one space between `%%` and `*`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk.

```
echo "$LISTNODES" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your List. I made an array for you:

```
declare -a LISTNODES=('name1 labels="{..}"' 'name2 labels="{...}"' 'name3 labels="{a b c}"')
for i in "${LISTNODES[@]}"; do
   echo "$i can be split into"
   echo "Name: ${i%% *}"
   echo "Labels: ${i#* }"
done
```